# Specific element in an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

I've had an idea for some proof involving infinite sets. Consider the infinite set $X$ and the element $x \in X$. According to the well-ordering theorem, any set can be well-ordered.

Would it be a valid to assign some index number $n$ to $x$ (we now write $x_n$), such that for all $x$ in $X$ we can say that $x_i < x_n$ if $i<n$ and $x_i > x_n$ if $i>n$?
Both the elements and the ordering in and of itself are of arbitrary kind.

Edit: thanks for all the answers.
Clarification: As part of a bigger problem I'm trying to show that there is a bijection $f:X\rightarrow X$ $\backslash \{x\}$ for the infinite set $X$ and the element $x \in X$ (which we call $x_n$ in the light of the above). It was my idea to define a function that maps some $x_i$ to itself if $i<n$ and any $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ if $i>n$ to circumvent $x_n$. So it is not necessary for me to find any least elements, use the standard ordering $\geq$ or use $\mathbb{N}$ as the index set.

Comment: When you assign indices from $\mathbb{N}$, you are automatically claiming that the set $X$ should be countable. In general, we cannot assign such indices to the elements of a set.

Comment: To continue @AniruddhaDeshmukh 's comment, well ordering only guarantees that subsets have a minimal element in the ordering (i.e., the "infinities" can only go to the right, not to the left). By no means does that guarantee countability, or any bijection with any set.

Comment: @DonThousand: It's called "hinting", but when you're using $i$ and $n$, you're hinting that your index set is $\Bbb N$. And when it's not, it's generally a good idea to point this out explicitly.

Comment: I've often seen the index $\alpha$ to avoid implications of countability.  If you assume the well ordering theorem (which requires the axiom of choice) I don't see much wrong with indexing $x_\alpha<x_\beta$ if and only if $\alpha<\beta$ but I dont see any point. The idea of indexing $X=\{x_\alpha\};\alpha\in A$ is to make an injection from $A\to X$. And what would be the point if we don't know anything more of $A$ than of $X$.  You might as well simply refer to the elements of $X$ directly.

Comment: @user24334 - If you are satisfied with your answer, then please check one of the green checks to close your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the ordering you've defined here, that is, an order of (<), is sufficient to ensure that any infinite set will suddenly have a least element. For example, take the set of the integers $\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-3,-2,-2,0,1,2,3,...\}$. Under the ordering you have described, which $i$ indexes the least element? For any index $i$ that you assign to the least element, I will find another index given by $i-1$ such that $x_{i-1} < x_i$. Even if you define a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ places the integers in a one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers, which is not difficult to do, the set of the integers still lacks a least element under the ordering of (<) you have defined.

From what I understand, in order to take an infinite set and make it well ordered, you have to change your definition of the ordering from the conventional (<). For example, in order to make $\mathbb{Z}$ well ordered, we define a new ordering, say ($\prec$), such that for any arbitrary $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $a \prec b$ whenever $|a| \le |b|$. If we define the ordering in this manner then we can order the set of integers as follows: $\{0, 1 ,-1, 2,-2,3, -3,...\}$ and thus make the set well-ordered. Under this new ordering that has been defined, the least element is now $0$ because for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a \ne 0$, then $|0| = 0 \lt |a|$. And as you can probably see, every nonempty subset will also have a least element under this new ordering.

So to answer your question, no, I don't think the ordering you're describing will be adequate prove something about all infinite sets being well ordered.

Answer (score 0):

As [Aniruddha Deshmukh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/438367/aniruddha) pointed out, you can't index $\ X\ $ with indices limited to a countable set, such as $\ \mathbb{N}\ $, unless $\ X\ $ is itself countable.  However, any well-ordered set is [order equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type#Order_type_of_well-orderings) to some [ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\ \omega\ $, which means that $\ X\ $ *can* be indexed by the set of *ordinal numbers* $\ \nu < \omega\ $ in such a way that $\ x_{\nu_1} < x_{\nu_2}\ $ if and only if $\ \nu_1 < \nu_2\ $. Moreover, for any given $\ x\in X\ $ and given $\ \nu<\omega\ $, it's possible to choose the indexing in such a way that $\ x_\nu = x\ $.  In particular, you *could*, if you wish, choose $\ \nu\ $ to be any of the *finite* ordinals $\ 0,1,2, \dots\ $.  If $\ X\ $ is uncountable, however, you can't do this for *all* $\ x\in X\ $, because, in that case, there must always be an uncountable subset of $\ X $ whose members will have to have infinite ordinals as indices.